# Textbox with transparent image to show background

Tags: vba, operating-system, transparent

I am a developer trying to make an operating system in VBA. On the login screen, there is a password box. I would like to make it transparent so that the user can see the UserForm's bitmap image through the text box. Is this possible. I'm also starting out on this project so a bit of help/explanation would really help please.

Kind Regards,
J

Comment: That just gives it no background. I want to have an image as a transparent grey for the textbox. So you have the UserForm bitmap, and the textbox has a grey transparent image, so you can so through the grey. How would I do this?. Thanks for your previous answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing the `BackStyle` property of the TextBox.

Let's say you're using VBA in Excel; you can make `TextBox1` transparent by changing `BackStyle` to `0`.

```
ActiveSheet.TextBox1.BackStyle = 0
```

Changing the property to `1` would render the TextBox opaque again.

Comment: That just gives it no background. I want to have an image as a transparent grey for the textbox. So you have the UserForm bitmap, and the textbox has a grey transparent image, so you can so through the grey. How would I do this?. Thanks for your previous answer.

Comment: @jj1064 I don't quite understand what you're trying to do. What do you mean by a `grey transparent image` ?

Comment: Basically, imagine a UserForm with an image of a dog. I want a textbox that is grey, but you can see through it. This would mean that you could see the image of the dog. An example would be a MacOS login screen. Is this possible? Cheers.